# jQUERY adding and removing class individually

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a form [click here to view](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QNNMZK). The form consists of a basic validation functionality, one character checks and the validates number fields. Once the validation checks it adds either the class `valid` (green) or `invalid` (red)

At the moment 'which can been seen in my demo' when the user fills out an input my validation check activates all input fields instead of one at a time.

Code snippet

```
var validInput = function(fieldName) {
    $(fieldName).css({
        "background-color": "rgba(229,254,205)"
    });
};

var inValidInput = function(fieldName) {
    $(fieldName).css({
        "background-color": "rgba(229,254,205)"
    })
};

// VALIDATOR FUNCTION FOR CHARACTERS
$('.characters').focusout(function() {
    var letters = /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/;
    if ($(this).val().match(letters)) {
        validInput('.characters');
        $('.valid-checked').addClass("checked").css("color", "rgb(36,199,90)");
        $('.invalid-checked').removeClass("invalid");
    } else {
        $('.invalid-checked').addClass("invalid").css("color", "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.92)");
        $('.valid-checked').removeClass("checked");
    }
});
```

Comment: you are not dealing with one element at a time.. you are using class selectors and playing with all..

Comment: so you want that red green on particular input i touch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointing out couple of mistakes from you,

1) `validInput('.characters');` Do not validate all the inputs with the class `.characters` validate only this input which triggered the event. so it must be `validInput(this);` , Pass the element to the function.

```
2) $('.valid-checked').addClass("checked").css("color", "rgb(36,199,90)");
            $('.invalid-checked').removeClass("invalid");
```

Here don't change the css of all the valid and invalid icons. Apply changes to only the icons that are wrapped with this input inside the `<div class="protect-field planner-form">` So trace this wrapper div from the input element, Then trace back to the icons and change only them.

```
var validInput = function(fieldName) {
    $(fieldName).css({
        "background-color": "rgba(229,254,205)"
    });
};

var inValidInput = function(fieldName) {
    $(fieldName).css({
        "background-color": "rgba(229,254,205)"
    })
};

// VALIDATOR FUNCTION FOR CHARACTERS
$('.characters').focusout(function() {
    var letters = /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/;
    var $inputWrapper = $(this).closest('.planner-form'); //get the wrapper of the input
    if ($(this).val().match(letters)) {
        validInput(this); //pass this input element to validate 

        // Trace down the appropriate icons and change.
        $inputWrapper.find('.valid-checked').addClass("checked").css("color", "rgb(36,199,90)");
        $inputWrapper.find('.invalid-checked').removeClass("invalid");
    } else {
        $inputWrapper.find('.invalid-checked').addClass("invalid").css("color", "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.92)");
        $inputWrapper.find('.valid-checked').removeClass("checked");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use $(this) in the call to validInput function.

Also, you need to use .siblings method on $(this) instead of using $('.valid-checked') and so on.

Comment: Didn't give you the entire solution coz the pleasure is in working it out by own :)

Answer (score 0):

Add css

```
.checked {
   display: inline;
}
.invalid {
   display: inline;
}
```

Use `this`.

```
validInput(this);//instead the class referance.
```

Then change the code which show hide the icons like following using `closest()`.

```
$(this).closest('.protect-field').find('.valid-checked');
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZZOry)

Answer (score 0):

you have too much code, overcomplicated html..

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOOPgW

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#validateForm input').focusout(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('characters'))
        {
          if($(this).val() != 'a'){
            $(this).next('.checker').css("background-color", "red").addClass('invalid');
          } //change this
        }
      else
        {
          if($(this).val() != 12345){
            $(this).next('.checker').css("background-color", "red").addClass('invalid');
          }
        }
  });
});
```

obviously not gonna do it all for ya, but thats the general idea of what you need.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see your problem is that your numbers validate function is failing. Each textbox is evaluated individually. This should fix your validator:

```
  $('.numbers').focusout(function() {
    var numbers = /^[-+]?\d+$/;
    if ($(this).val().match(numbers)) {
      validInput('.numbers');
      $('.valid-checked').addClass("checked").css("color", "rgb(36,199,90)");
      $('.invalid-checked').removeClass("invalid");
    } else {
      $('.invalid-checked').addClass("invalid").css("color", "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.92)");
      $('.valid-checked').removeClass("checked");
    }
});
```

The other problem is that your textbox for name of first child is using the numbers class which should actually be your characters class.